# How to programmatically render a webform to display specific Elements

Tags: 8, forms

I have tried this way but not able to hide "confirmation_id" element.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $sid = NULL) {


$my_webform_machinename = 'request_form';
$my_form = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load($my_webform_machinename);
$my_form['elements']['flexbox_layout']['confirmation_id']['#access'] = FALSE;


return [      
    'form' => [
    '#type' => 'webform',
    '#webform' => $my_form,
    '#sid' => $sid, 
    ],

]; 

}
```

Comment: `$webform` is undefined. Should be `$my_form['elements']['flexbox_layout']['confirmation_id']['#access'] = FALSE;`

Comment: Hi, I did tried in that way it's not working.

Comment: These are two different question, the code shown in the question renders a webform programmatically in a custom controller (not buildForm). To access `$form` and display specific elements you need a form alter hook, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-programmatically-hide-and-show-webform-elements

Answer (score 0):

To hide custom field in webfrom you need to use the [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.8.x).

```
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_webform_submission_request_form_add_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $elements = &Drupal\webform\Utility\WebformFormHelper::flattenElements($form['elements']);

  $elements['flexbox_layout']['confirmation_id']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

To get specific form elements you can use [`getSubmissionForm()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/blob/8.x-5.x/src/WebformInterface.php#L613) method:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $sid = NULL) {
  $my_webform_machinename = 'request_form';
  $my_form = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load($my_webform_machinename);

  $webform = $my_form->getSubmissionForm();

  $form['my_field'] = $webform['elements']['flexbox_layout']['confirmation_id'];

  return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
}
```